# .net added client certificate but still recieve an invalid certificate

Tags: .net, ssl, certificate

I made a little Client Server Example with SSL/TLS. All is working fine when i test it on one machine but when i have my Server on a different machine my client gets revoked.

Basically the client creates a certificate (SelfSigned) which i copy over to the Server. Now the Server stores this certificate in his trusted certificates but when i try to connect to my server i get revoked.

```
X509Store^ store = gcnew X509Store(StoreName::Root, StoreLocation::LocalMachine); //windows Truststore!
    store->Open(OpenFlags::ReadWrite);
    store->Add(cert);
    store->Close();
```

I can see that this works cause the certificate is in my trusted root certificates but when i try to connect to my server he gets me a list of certificates (the certificate_authorities from the RFC) and the just added certificate is not one of them.

I start the Server with the following code:

```
TcpClient^ client = serverSocket->AcceptTcpClient();
SslStream^ sslStream;
sslStream = gcnew SslStream(client->GetStream(), false);
sslStream->AuthenticateAsServer(cert, true, SslProtocols::Tls, true);
```

The authenticateServer part is where i get a

```
System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.
```

What i get from the debug is that everything is working good in the handshake to the part where he requests the Client certificate (client is in java so this is java debug)

```
*** ServerHello, TLSv1
RandomCookie:  GMT: 1449660634 bytes = { 128, 20, 156, 73, 60, 13, 107, 144, 124, 0, 148, 240, 5, 94, 16, 14, 25, 189, 27, 55, 27, 185, 101, 236, 44, 8, 144, 97 }
Session ID:  {229, 66, 0, 0, 90, 25, 188, 202, 203, 197, 32, 150, 47, 124, 255, 204, 43, 45, 239, 205, 144, 194, 235, 58, 116, 90, 125, 192, 127, 44, 131, 95}
Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
Compression Method: 0
Extension renegotiation_info, renegotiated_connection: <empty>
***
%% Initialized:  [Session-14, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA]
** TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
[read] MD5 and SHA1 hashes:  len = 81
0000: 02 00 00 4D 03 01 56 68   11 DA 80 14 9C 49 3C 0D  ...M..Vh.....I<.
...
0050: 00                                                 .
*** Certificate chain
chain [0] = [
[
  Version: V3
  Subject: C=C, ST=ST, L=L, O=O, OU=OU, CN=Server
  Signature Algorithm: SHA512withRSA, OID = 1.2.840.113549.1.1.13

  Key:  Sun RSA public key, 2048 bits
  modulus: 1808...291064931634275033537
  public exponent: 65537
  Validity: [From: Wed Dec 09 10:01:12 CET 2015,
               To: Fri Dec 09 10:01:12 CET 2016]
  Issuer: C=C, ST=ST, L=L, O=O, OU=OU, CN=Server
  SerialNumber: [    2ad334c8 74494189]

]
  Algorithm: [SHA512withRSA]
  Signature:
0000: 2A 69 12 08 ED 38 75 B9   DD 63 FE E3 2B 20 52 E3  *i...8u..c..+ R.
...
00F0: FB D5 FC EB F2 63 24 A4   AD F9 31 31 CE A8 02 6A  .....c$...11...j

]
***
Found trusted certificate:
[
[
  Version: V3
  Subject: C=C, ST=ST, L=L, O=O, OU=OU, CN=Server
  Signature Algorithm: SHA512withRSA, OID = 1.2.840.113549.1.1.13

  Key:  Sun RSA public key, 2048 bits
  modulus: 18081618984...264273424659291064931634275033537
  public exponent: 65537
  Validity: [From: Wed Dec 09 10:01:12 CET 2015,
               To: Fri Dec 09 10:01:12 CET 2016]
  Issuer: C=C, ST=ST, L=L, O=O, OU=OU, CN=Server
  SerialNumber: [    2ad334c8 74494189]

]
  Algorithm: [SHA512withRSA]
  Signature:
0000: 2A 69 12 08 ED 38 75 B9   DD 63 FE E3 2B 20 52 E3  *i...8u..c..+ R.
...
00F0: FB D5 FC EB F2 63 24 A4   AD F9 31 31 CE A8 02 6A  .....c$...11...j

]
[read] MD5 and SHA1 hashes:  len = 880
0000: 0B 00 03 6C 00 03 69 00   03 66 30 82 03 62 30 82  ...l..i..f0..b0.
...
3FB0: 65 20 6C 61 20 41 62 6F   67 61 63 69 61           e la Abogacia
ReadThread2, READ: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 16317
*** CertificateRequest
Cert Types: RSA, DSS, ECDSA
Cert Authorities:
<EMAILADDRESS=info@netlock.hu, CN=NetLock Minositett Kozjegyzoi (Class QA) Tanusitvanykiado, OU=Tanusitvanykiadok, O=NetLock Halozatbiztonsagi Kft., L=Budapest, C=HU>
... //all certifications my server trust but the client certificate aint one of them
<CN=Autoridad de Certificacion de la Abogacia, O=Consejo General de la Abogacia NIF:Q-2863006I, C=ES>
[read] MD5 and SHA1 hashes:  len = 16317
0000: 0D 00 3F B9 03 01 02 40   3F B3 00 CC 30 81 C9 31  ..?....@?...0..1
...
3FB0: 65 20 6C 61 20 41 62 6F   67 61 63 69 61           e la Abogacia
[Raw read]: length = 5
0000: 16 03 01 00 04                                     .....
[Raw read]: length = 4
0000: 0E 00 00 00                                        ....
ReadThread2, READ: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 4
*** ServerHelloDone
[read] MD5 and SHA1 hashes:  len = 4
0000: 0E 00 00 00                                        ....
Warning: no suitable certificate found - continuing without client authentication
*** Certificate chain
<Empty>
***
*** ECDHClientKeyExchange
ECDH Public value:  { 4, 196, 28, 72, 78, 63, 148, 184, 247, 70, 246, 4, 21, 150, 30, 45, 74, 174, 199, 152, 153, 149, 232, 117, 118, 155, 206, 122, 168, 135, 155, 250, 130, 128, 35, 109, 198, 246, 95, 24, 150, 55, 162, 118, 227, 205, 207, 54, 147, 163, 44, 112, 167, 136, 21, 126, 34, 98, 157, 205, 44, 117, 143, 213, 85 }
[write] MD5 and SHA1 hashes:  len = 77
0000: 0B 00 00 03 00 00 00 10   00 00 42 41 04 C4 1C 48  ..........BA...H
...
0040: A7 88 15 7E 22 62 9D CD   2C 75 8F D5 55           ...."b..,u..U
ReadThread2, WRITE: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 77
[Raw write]: length = 82
0000: 16 03 01 00 4D 0B 00 00   03 00 00 00 10 00 00 42  ....M..........B
...
0050: D5 55                                              .U
SESSION KEYGEN:
PreMaster Secret:
0000: AD 6C 40 88 86 19 1C 0B   76 67 9E 67 00 65 F2 5F  .l@.....vg.g.e._
0010: 8B C7 87 1D B6 77 66 1E   96 47 49 CC 29 F1 EF 3E  .....wf..GI.)..>
CONNECTION KEYGEN:
Client Nonce:
0000: 56 68 11 DE 90 96 ED 7F   AC 28 50 1B 83 59 E5 50  Vh.......(P..Y.P
0010: 23 C5 A2 6D 59 B6 42 AF   78 DB 0A 7C FF A6 EF D7  #..mY.B.x.......
Server Nonce:
0000: 56 68 11 DA 80 14 9C 49   3C 0D 6B 90 7C 00 94 F0  Vh.....I<.k.....
0010: 05 5E 10 0E 19 BD 1B 37   1B B9 65 EC 2C 08 90 61  .^.....7..e.,..a
Master Secret:
0000: AE 80 BB 88 5C 64 65 98   FA A6 5C 9F 01 1D 2B 39  ....\de...\...+9
...
0020: 1D D9 6D 04 98 98 03 80   F9 9C 91 ED 9A F5 E9 F9  ..m.............
Client MAC write Secret:
0000: 05 84 E0 18 90 80 E0 D9   BC 52 13 49 29 E0 56 18  .........R.I).V.
0010: 31 D0 A2 CF                                        1...
Server MAC write Secret:
0000: 19 9B 99 44 55 59 CD 11   52 9B 5F BE 38 34 01 2E  ...DUY..R._.84..
0010: E2 67 0C C8                                        .g..
Client write key:
0000: 78 0E 20 84 70 87 8D 81   F7 DF 02 BD EC 1C C3 7D  x. .p...........
Server write key:
0000: 57 F6 B1 47 A6 57 83 68   F2 28 54 92 03 8A 17 C7  W..G.W.h.(T.....
Client write IV:
0000: DA F9 8E 8E 10 0C 21 EC   BB 63 AC 16 2C 33 B1 9A  ......!..c..,3..
Server write IV:
0000: 7A 18 E2 2F 4D AD 1D 01   7F 68 A5 CF 6D FC 84 8A  z../M....h..m...
ReadThread2, WRITE: TLSv1 Change Cipher Spec, length = 1
[Raw write]: length = 6
0000: 14 03 01 00 01 01                                  ......
*** Finished
verify_data:  { 9, 94, 87, 61, 94, 171, 69, 203, 42, 71, 108, 59 }
***
[write] MD5 and SHA1 hashes:  len = 16
0000: 14 00 00 0C 09 5E 57 3D   5E AB 45 CB 2A 47 6C 3B  .....^W=^.E.*Gl;
Padded plaintext before ENCRYPTION:  len = 48
0000: 14 00 00 0C 09 5E 57 3D   5E AB 45 CB 2A 47 6C 3B  .....^W=^.E.*Gl;
...
0020: 6E DA 09 6B 0B 0B 0B 0B   0B 0B 0B 0B 0B 0B 0B 0B  n..k............
ReadThread2, WRITE: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 48
[Raw write]: length = 53
0000: 16 03 01 00 30 0D 0B CE   0B 65 78 2F 19 2D EC 2A  ....0....ex/.-.*
...
0030: 52 96 52 F8 49                                     R.R.I
[Raw read]: length = 5
0000: 14 03 01 00 01                                     .....
[Raw read]: length = 1
0000: 01                                                 .
ReadThread2, READ: TLSv1 Change Cipher Spec, length = 1
[Raw read]: length = 5
0000: 16 03 01 00 30                                     ....0
[Raw read]: length = 48
0000: 60 52 C2 47 73 E3 B6 65   36 CE A3 A9 FC 60 0C 7F  `R.Gs..e6....`..
...
0020: DE 06 62 17 FA 9C 22 FE   1E E5 2A C0 88 21 3E BC  ..b..."...*..!>.
ReadThread2, READ: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 48
Padded plaintext after DECRYPTION:  len = 48
ReadThread, handling exception: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
```

So to make it all short:

How can i make my server trust the clients certificate and include it in the list of certificate_authorities. Can I Make my server not send a list of certificate_authorities?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a working solution. Appearently there is a bug in Windows Server.

[Clients cannot make connections if you require client certificates on a Web site or if you use IAS in Windows Server 2003 (up 23.12.2015)](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/933430)

I just told the Server not to send a Trusted Client CA list since this is not critical for my application (Workaround Method 3). Since this is just a Workaround, note that this only applies to the given Enviroment.